# Suggestions of GHS-compliant labelling software

Tags: software

Having amassed a rather large collection of reagents and products from previous years of chemistry experiments, I find rather annoying that their labels aren't even close to being standardized to the GHS rules.

Each supplier has its own variation, some GHS-compliant, some not, and of course for the end products of the experiments there is no standardization at all since they weren't purchased. I try to find a pre-made label for said compound on the internet, print and use it.

If there is no pre-made template for it, the next step is to find a MSDS and fill in the data in one of many online label generators. Tedious, and prone to error. And online generators come and go offline all the time meaning after some time there are several different "formats" around.

To complicate things more I do not feel comfortable at all letting some random site know that I have this or that chemical.

That said, I ask for suggestions of software for GHS-compliant label generation.

- Offline only
- Windows/Linux
- Can use standard inkjet/thermal/dot-matrix printers (not proprietary printers)

And bonus if:

- Has internal database of chemicals. If not, well, it would be a one-time effort to input the data.
- Is open-source (or is cheap)

Comment: Prior adoption of GHS symbols, our group gave [open enventory](http://www.open-enventory.de/index_en.html) a shot (open source, APGL; runs in Ubuntu) as comprising both a chemical inventory + label generator + electronic lab book. Thanks to the INSTALL folder and help by the IT it run some time. If fed by a .csv file of chemicals present, it fetched the MSDS data from the vendors and public sources. But it was not enough «ChemDraw like» (there are interfaces to an ELN and inventory) for the elder folks, and the department adopted an ERP billing (no chem) software by SAP to track the bottles.

Comment: Maybe the current version (updated February this year) adjusted the label generator to include the GHS symbols on the labels to print (which you may purchase as sticker labels a little bit smaller than 2 x 2 cm wide, too).